# puppetrun not reporting client errors

Tags: cluster

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [puppetrun not reporting client errors](https://serverfault.com/questions/14887/puppetrun-not-reporting-client-errors)

puppetrun doesn't report errors my puppetclients encounter.  for instance, if I put jibberish into site.pp and run puppetd --test on the clients I get an error.  if I run puppetrun on the puppetmaster it says the client finished with exit code 0.  Shouldn't it finish with an error code so that I can easily know there's an error in a manifest file?

Answer (score 2):

puppetrun only reports the success or failure of starting the run on a particular node, not the success or failure of that run.  Look at puppets reporting capability if you want to get results of failed runs.

Comment: In particular, tagmail with a tag of "error" is very useful.